# Nested code blocks and subshells in fish script

Tags: bash, fish

I am working on converting one [bash script](https://github.com/bellecp/fast-p/blob/gawk/p) to fish. I did most of it already, however there is a complex piece which has several nested and chained blocks.

Consider the following simplified piece in bash. Don't read too much into logic or commands, just follow the structure and pay attention to two subshells in `()` redirected to `comm`.

```
dummy () {
    {
    comm -13 \
        <(cat $CACHEDLIST | gawk  '{print $1}' FS='\t' OFS='\t') \
        <(cat $PDFLIST | gawk '{print $1}' FS='\t' OFS='\t') \
    } | fzf
}
```

I converted all `{}` blocks to `begin; end`. Then there are two subshell blocks redirected to `comm -13` which I also converted to `begin; end` fish blocks and the overall block is piped to `fzf`. So the end result is quite straightforward:

```
function dummy
    begin
        comm -13 \
             <begin; echo "Arg1"; end \
             <begin; echo "Arg2"; end \
    end | fzf
end
```

If I run this tiny piece in shell I get:

`(line 7): 'end' outside of a block`

How come? My only guess is that line continuation is not respected, because the issue is definitely with two `<begin; ...; end \` lines.

Comment: `<(...)` is a single construct--a process substitution--not a redirection plus a subshell. See https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9017996 for a possible translation into `fish`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to translate this is to use an explicit named pipe in place of `bash`'s process substitution construct. Note that the braces around `comm` aren't necessary, as there is only one command in the command group. That translates to one less begin-end pair in the `fish` function.

```
function dummy
    begin
        mkfifo p1 p2
        gawk '{print $1}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' "$CACHEDLIST" > p1 &
        gawk '{print $1}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' "$PDFLIST" > p2 &
        comm -13 p1 p2 | fzf
        rm p1 p2
    end
```

(You may want to make this more robust by creating `p1` and `p2` in a temp directory and making sure they get removed in the event of any error.)

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using `(command | psub)` construct. Your version also  works, although I already got more issues down the line, which made me question my choice of fish :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you've already solved your problem, but for posterity:

```
function dummy 
    comm -13 (cut -f1 $CACHEDLIST | psub) (cut -f1 $PDFLIST | psub) | fzf
end
```

Comment: Yes, I used this approach actually.